# Inserting record if the ID is not in the database and update it elsewise

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data into my database. I'm able to insert it using `INSERT INTO`. However I want to check, if the database already has the ID and if it has I want it to just update the records.

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT Fuid FROM users WHERE Fuid='$fuid_db'");

//IF the user is new
if(empty($check))
{
  $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (Fuid, Ffname, Femail) VALUES ('$fuid_db', '$ffname_db', '$femail_db'");
} 
else 
{ 
//ELSE update the information
  $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET Ffname='$ffname_db', Femail='$femail_db' WHERE Fuid='$fuid_db'");
}
```

How come this is not working? I'm using `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL)`,
but I'm not getting any errors. It seems like the issue is the "checking" before inserting. Without the checking part it works fine but now it's not inserting anything.

Comment: have you use any framework and post your connection code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

`$db->query()` returns an (maybe empty) [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-result.php) object. So `empty($check)` evaluates to `false` (since [`empty($var)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `true` only if `$var` is zero, `false`, an empty string, an empty array or `null`) and thus an `UPDATE` is performed, no matter if there is a corresponding `id` or not.

To check if there is a record you have to use `$check->num_rows` to get the number of records containing the `id`.

#### Better

The [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) command should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO users (Fuid, Ffname, Femail) 
  VALUES ('$fuid_db', '$ffname_db', '$femail_db') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users 
  SET Ffname = '$ffname_db', Femail = '$femail_db'
```

This way you don't have to make a `SELECT` first, so you reduce the number of database calls.

*Notice*: This only works, if `Fuid` is set as a `unique key` (or `primary key`).

### Security

The way you use the SQL commands is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php).

Using prepared statements, your code would look like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Fuid, Ffname, Femail) 
  VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users 
  SET Ffname = ?, Femail = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('issss',$fuid_db,$ffname_db, $femail_db,$ffname_db, $femail_db)
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all the information and thanks for the update! Been trying this today and I got stuck whenever I was using "on duplicate key", the Fuid is set to "varchar(100)" not primary. So you might have helped me with that issue aswell! Will have to change in the database to primary key, The same goes for the prepared statements method right? Since I'm now redoing it that way. Once again thanks for all the help! Will report back if I get stuck again with this.

Comment: I'm now using the prepared statement example you mentioned above. However it's not inserting anything and It's not giving me any errors. I suspect the issue is how I setup my database. For the database. This is my SQL code for creating the table `'Fuid' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL` and then at the end I have `PRIMARY KEY('Fuid')` Should that not be correct?

Comment: @asdasd If there is an error in your SQL, you can see it by looking at [`$stmt->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php). If this does not help, try to track down the problem as far as possible and open an new question.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, for security reasons you should not insert value that way. 
But if we ignore it for now, you can instead use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) as below provided that Fuid is a primary key

```
INSERT INTO users (Fuid, Ffname, Femail) VALUES ('$fuid_db', '$ffname_db', '$femail_db') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users SET Ffname = '$ffname_db', Femail = '$femail_db'
```